# Metadata vs Stored Data?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, cloud, bigdata, search-engine

What do they mean by separating metadata from stored data? When I create HTML pages, I put meta data, but how is that different from stored data?

> The architecture of the cloud giants' distributed file systems
>   separates the metadata (the data about the content) from the stored
>   data itself. That allows for high volumes of parallel reading and
>   writing of data across multiple replicas, and the tossing of concepts
>   like "file locking" out the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of metadata as data that describes other data. For example, if I created a Word document, there might be some metadata such as owner/creator, file size, date created/modified, file format, etc. whereas the actual data would be the document itself. Normally, that data would be part of the stored data, but I think the article you're referencing is saying that the data is separated to make things more efficient.